# Limit Django filter query set by a N number of field

Tags: python, django, set

I think I cannot well express myself with words so I can put some code so you can understand me better

I have a model

```
class Obj(models.Model):
  foo = models.IntegerField()
```

Then I have 8 objects where.

```
obj1.foo = 1
obj2.foo = 1
obj3.foo = 1
obj4.foo = 2
obj5.foo = 2
obj6.foo = 2
obj7.foo = 3
obj8.foo = 3
```

With the query set

```
objs = Obj.objects.all()
obj = QuerySet[obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4, obj5, obj6, obj7, obj8]
```

Then the query that I want is limit the obj by foo

```
filtered_obj = QuerySet[
 obj1,  # foo=1
 obj2,  # foo=1
 obj4,  # foo=2
 obj5,  # foo=2
 obj7,  # foo=3
 obj8.  # foo=3
]
```

I don't want repeated fields more than 2 times.

Answer (score 0):

Use Filter instead of **all** and pass **foo** as param

```
obqs = Obj.objects.filter(foo=1)[:2]
# returns QuerySet[obj1, obj2]
obqs = Obj.objects.filter(foo=3)[:2]
# returns  QuerySet[obj7, obj8]
```

Refer [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/queries/)

Comment: `obqs = Obj.objects.filter(foo=1)` will return `# returns QuerySet[obj1, obj2, obj3]`.  You could do `obqs = Obj.objects.filter(foo=1)[:2]` to limit the result to 2 objects, but I think the OP wants to do this using *one* query, and I do not know if that is possible.

Comment: missed that thing

Comment: But I don't know the value of foo, I just want that anything that foo value is... it won't return more than 2 objs with that value of foo (all in a single query set)

Comment: if you want 2 elements irrespective of  foo then obqs = Obj.objects.all()[:2]